# Client-Server architectur for Apps

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I built up my server for my app which is running on Android. And i will hear some opinions from you if the setup is acceptable or complete wrong. So the architecture works like request-respone.
The user will log-in, every app start and will get a new session id.
The client and the server does not have a keep-alive connection. The connection is getting cut every request. For every command on the server, the session id need to get checked first, and then the command or request can be calculated. After everything is done the connection will cut. I was thinking about something that the connection will be held to the server and this gives me the possibility to send from the server some data directly to the client. This could have many usages. But on the other hand its not thread "able". Because i will have to synchronize the socket access and share 1 socket object between all classes and activity, this isnt in my opinion a good way. But am still wondering how other apps or online games could sent data or messages directly to the client. This means that a connection is held. I think that they doing it seperated in a service or something like this. This a new problem im facing. I could use firebase cloud messaging, but this is very slow when more as 100 threads are running on the server. A better solution where, to code a second server program, which is running seprated from the main server and keeps a connection to the client. This would be my solution.

What i just want to know if my architecture is good to go or its a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, opening and closing the connection is a good practice, because the connection is relatively an expensive resource.
So, I would say that yes, you're good to go with the architecture that you currently have implemented.

- Open connection
- Execute operation
- Close connection